# A failed review audit on a question that looks for resource

Tags: support, review-queues, disputed-review-audits

I failed [a review audit on Close Votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5386658) today:

[image]

I vote to close it as off-topic because it looks like a question that's looking for recommendation of resource. Doesn't it meet this reason?

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It does. But as you can see by the answers, a bunch of low-rep users who couldn't close it (and probably voted it up) viewed and answered it. You're one of three people who failed a review audit on that terrible question.

It's closed down now and won't appear again.

Comment: I hope that the statistics of these unlucky reviewers were adjusted to not include this landmine-like question.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo: We all miss some reviews from time to time due to the automatic selection of the 'good' or 'bad' review questions. If it happens sometime, it is no problem.